# File server permission

Tags: permissions

I am trying to give 2 users rwx access to a new shared directory i have created that will hold some shared documents. The directory is `/srv/shared` The 2 users are Mason and Bill that will be accessing the files. I would like both users to be able to rwx any newly created files/directories by each other.

I have added Bill to the group Mason with `sudo usermod -a -G mason bill`
I then changed the `/srv/shared` ownership to Mason and group Mason with `sudo chown mason:mason /srv/shared`

I then tried creating a directory in `/srv/shared` logged in as bill with mkdir `/srv/shared/test` but got access denied. I tried giving the directory chmod 755 permissions but that still gave Bill access denied when creating files. When i gave chmod permissions 777 Bill could then create directories and files without an issue.

Just trying to work out what I have done wrong for this to only work with 777 permissions which is not really what i want to allow?

Comment: How are you sharing?  Multi user Linux system? CIFS/Samba server? NFS? SSHFS mounts?

Answer (score 2):

Add the users `mason` and `bill` to a new group, lets call them `mbshare`. Then change the permissions and group on the share point to match the new group. Finally add the users to the group.

```
// create a new group
sudo groupadd mbshare
// change the permissions on the sharepoint
sudo chgrp -R mbshare /path/to/share
sudo chmod -R 2775 /path/to/share
// make the users part of the share group
sudo usermod -aG mbshare mason
sudo usermod -aG mbshare bill
```

Now `mason` and `bill` can create and edit files in `/path/to/share`.

The `2` in the `2775` permission flag means: (setGID bit) new files will have the same group as the directory and subdirectories inherit the same as parent.

If you only want `mason` and `bill` to see the files within the share, use `2770` instead of `2775`.

The advantages of creating a custom group are significant.

- It is easy to add or remove a new user to the group.
- You can quickly see who has access to the group.
- You can remove any user without the need to change any permissions.
- Keeps things very neat and tidy :]

**Edit:** Corrected a few "from memory" errors.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, will give it a try. Would i need to create a user though named mbshare to be able to chown mbshare:mbshare /path/to/share

Comment: The `mbshare` group name was just an example name. You can call the group (almost) anything you like within the rules of a group name. For example: `internalshare`, `groupshare`, `projectname`, `sharedjunk`. What ever you call the group, substitute that in place of `mbshare` in the `chown`.

Comment: I see what you mean regarding the share name, i thought chown 'mbshare:mbshare' means change ownership of this directory to user mbshare and group mbshare. Obviously user mbshare does not exist only the group mbshare does.

Comment: @Mason Fixed a number of errors.

Answer (score 0):

It should be 775. Since both of them belong to same group. The group should have rwx right. The first 7 for the owner and second 7 for the group.